# show custom bottom sheet when selected from 'share' feature

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When I select my app through the 'Share' feature in another app, can I float a custom bottom sheet without switching to my app? My app is developed as a Flutter.

Comment: Have you tried the [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) packages? [This tutorial](https://youtu.be/My_TAyIk1rA?si=FdGGfYbBSYWhKgOn) may help to create share with bottom sheet in android.